# How to do a controller wait for a response sent from a service throutout a resolve?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm working in an Ionic project, and would like to pass an object from a **service**, to a **controller**, throughout a **resolve** on my router. However, the controller does not receive the object. In fact, this is an ascynchronous operation and I think, that the return in my service occurs before the promisse returns. How do I resolve this?

Thanks

I have a route in an **app.js**.

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

   $stateProvider
   .state('home', {
      url: '/',
      templateUrl: 'templates/home.html',
      controller: 'MainCtrl as vm',
      resolve: {
         weather: function(MyService) {
             return MyService.getData();
         }
      });

   $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
});
```

The **Service** is here:

```
.factory('MyService', function($http) {

   var data = {};
   $http.get('http://something.api?format=json')
   .then(
      function(res) {
         data = res.data;
      },
      function(err) {
         data = err.status;
      });

    return {
       getData: function() {
          return data;
       }
    }
});
```

And finally, my **Controller** is...

```
.controller('MainCtrl', function(weather) {

   var vm = this;
   vm.weather = weather;
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the $http request for the weather data inside the getData() function of your service and return the $http promise from the function.

```
.factory('MyService', function($http) {

    function getData() {
        return $http.get('http://something.api?format=json')
            .then(function(res) {
                return res.data;
            });
    }

    return {
        getData: getData
    };
});
```

Now, you can just return this promise from the resolve in your route definition just how you have done it.

Comment: I Prashant, it seems work, but, ti returns a promisse object, intead of a pure object. If you put a console.log(getData()) or console.log(getData) before the final return, you get  the response Promise {$$state: Object}.

Comment: That's correct, you then attach a success or error callback to the promise object using a then(successCallback, errorCallback) function. And if you return the promise object in your resolve, ngRoute makes sure that the promise is resolved and the resulting pure object is injected in your controller.

Comment: Thanks Prashant, this worked fine, but I had to change the return to getData: getData()